# heroku cedar console

Tags: heroku

I've been trying to get a heroku console session going on cedar and am having no joy.

The old way was:

```
heroku console
```

I understand the new way involves 2 steps:

```
heroku run bash
```

then

```
$ rails console
```

but at the heroku run bash stage i keep geting:

```
heroku run bash
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.1
 !    
 !    Timeout awaiting process
```

so i checked there isn't a port blocking issue and

```
telnet rendezvous.heroku.com 5000
```

gives

```
Trying 50.19.103.36... 
Connected to ec2-50-19-103-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com. 
Escape character is '^]'.
```

which is as expected i think

what am i doing wrong and what do i need to do to get this console up and running?

Thanks!

PS I have tried - heroku run console - also, and that times out too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In cedar every command that needs to be attached to terminal uses run.
ex:

```
heroku run console
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

When its not necessary to be attached don't use the `run`:
ex: `heroku logs`

Answer (score 1):

The new way is `heroku run console`

Answer (score 0):

Ok - it was obvious after a few hours of sleep. Simply had to update the heroku gem that had got corrupted somehow on my mac. If you have something like this problem, then do that first...